# How can simple classicall things be described with string theory?

Tags: classical-mechanics, string-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

It is of course overkill to use string theory for this, but I am still interested in how, for example, the trajectory of a horizontal throw of a mass point could be derived from string theory, after all, everything should be available in this theoretical framework to derive something like this.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but for specificity, maybe you should explicitly say that you want to know how string theory would describe motion of a point mass in space, or whatever it is that you are envisioning...

Comment: Have you studied quantum mechanics?   " String theory attempts to reconcile general relativity (gravity) with quantum physics    https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/science/physics/string-theory-for-dummies-cheat-sheet-209405/

Comment: The up quarks, down quarks, and electrons making up the Earth — and the virtual gluons, photons, and gravitons binding them into nucleons, atoms, and a planet — are strings. Similarly, the ball you throw is made of strings. The virtual gravitons mediating the gravitational force between the ball and the Earth are strings. General Relativity [is a classical limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/does-string-theory-disagree-with-general-relativity) of string theory. Newtonian gravity is the non-relativistic limit of GR. Bingo! A parabola!

Comment: However, I am not a string theorist, so this may be too naïve.

Comment: Hi Leonard. Welcome to Phys.SE.  What answer are you seeking beyond one that mentions the standard hierarchy of theories? Suggestion: Consider to limit the scope of the post, e.g. to only ask how _classical_ string theory could model  _classical_ point particles.